# On button click copy a <p> text to a input box

Tags: javascript, button

I have a this text:

```
<p>01A001-Z03-71021</p>
```

and i have this button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary2">Add to Cart</a>
```

and i havet this input box:

```
<input class="" placeholder="" data-role="tagsinput" id="cart" value="">
```

How to copy the text in the input box when i press the button, by using JS.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everybody, is working great.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var handler = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('cart').value = event.target.innerText;
  }
</script>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary2" onclick="handler(event)">Add to Cart</a>
<input class="" placeholder="" data-role="tagsinput" id="cart" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25z1m2b6/) using your html code (only)

  ```
     $(document).on("click",".btn-secondary2",function(event){
         $("input").val($("p").text());
     });
  ```
- Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25z1m2b6/1/) where I set IDs on elements for proper call

Comment: Your solution is in Jquery not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onclick and innerHtml function of javascript.

HTML

```
<p id='textValue'>01A001-Z03-71021</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary2" onclick="copyValue()">Add to Cart</a>
<input id='mytext' class="" placeholder="" data-role="tagsinput" id="cart" value="">
```

JS

```
function copyValue() {
    var valueToCopy = document.getElementById("textValue").innerHTML";
    var elem = document.getElementById("mytext");
    elem.value = valueToCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign a unique ID to the paragraph and the button to use this method below. Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yenvpkv6/

```
function getText() {
    var inp = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("cart").value = inp;
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("run");
    getText();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try something like this (with addEventListener function):

```
var element = document.getElementById('button');
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph")
    ,   cart      = document.getElementById("cart");
    cart.value = paragraph.innerHTML;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/totw2L6j/

Comment: Also please notice, that if you're using IE < 9, then you should use `element.attachEvent('onclick', function() { /* ... */ });` instead.